# Unable to access folder with full stops in it

Tags: java, directory

I have the following code which shows a folder without any full stops in it and java successfully detects it as a folder, but if the folder contains any full stops in it, it does not detect it as a folder or even a file even though it exists

```
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
files.add("F:/some dir/");
files.add("F:\\somedir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it");
files.add("F:\\somedir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\\");
files.add("F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it");
files.add("F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/");

files.add("F:\\somedir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\\sub directory");
files.add("F:\\somedir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\\sub directory\\");
files.add("F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/sub directory");
files.add("F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/sub directory//");

for(String filePath : files)
{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    System.out.println("===== " + filePath + " ===== ");
    System.out.println("IsDirectory = " + file.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("IsFile = " + file.isFile());
}
```

and here is the output on my system (windows 8.1 64 bit jre 1.8.0_25)

```
===== F:/some dir/ ===== 
IsDirectory = true
IsFile = false
===== F:\somedir\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
===== F:\somedir\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\ ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
===== F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
===== F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/ ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
===== F:\somedir\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\sub directory ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
===== F:\somedir\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\sub directory\ ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
===== F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/sub directory ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
===== F:/somedir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/sub directory// ===== 
IsDirectory = false
IsFile = false
```

Comment: Are you sure it exists? It looks like you have removed the space in `some dir` - could that be causing your problem?

Comment: DId you check whether actual folders are exist on the disk?

Comment: God this made me laugh.  Please don't be offended.  I laugh because I've had the same thing happen to me.  Is it the dots? The slashes?    Arg!  You can work your but off simplifing the code to help you find the bug but sometimes you really just need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: second pair of eyes is always good especially when you have been pulling your hair out for a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead - I have fixed what could be typos:

```
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
files.add("F:/some dir/");
files.add("F:\\some dir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it");
files.add("F:\\some dir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\\");
files.add("F:/some dir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it");
files.add("F:/some dir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/");

files.add("F:\\some dir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\\sub directory");
files.add("F:\\some dir\\some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it\\sub directory\\");
files.add("F:/some dir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/sub directory");
files.add("F:/some dir/some.other.directory.with.full.stops.in.it/sub directory//");

for(String filePath : files)
{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    System.out.println("===== " + filePath + " ===== ");
    System.out.println("IsDirectory = " + file.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("IsFile = " + file.isFile());
}
```

Comment: yeah typos... was concentrating too much on the end folder to notice the blunder. thanks for noticing.